# Django dummie question

Tags: django

Hi i'm beginning to learn django and i'm facing same trouble .Could you guys help  with a silly question .

i have a nav menu at my base.html it works fine  but the problem is that when i click in one of the links , my view.py render_to_response correctly to the page , but once i got there if i click again in this link it just and to my url the same pattern and my urls.py dont find it.
Same thing like that.

First time click :

//127.0.0.1:8000/cliente/cadastro/

Second time click:

//127.0.0.1:8000/cliente/cadastro/cliente/cadastro/

I belive that is the same problem i'm facing with admin

First time click :

//127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

It works.

Second time click:

//127.0.0.1:8000/cliente/cadastro/admin/

it does not Work.

The url.py is the follow:

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
     # Example:

    (r'^', include('cliente.urls')),

      (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   )

   #seta os arquivos estaticos , css e javascript
     urlpatterns += patterns('',

(r'^/css/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
{'document_root':'/home/lioy/django_projects/terrasis/css/'}),

(r'^/js/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
{'document_root':'/home/lioy/django_projects/terrasis/js/'}),

   )
```

the include('cliente.urls') :

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('cliente.views',

 (r'^$', 'home'),
 (r'^cliente/cadastro/$', 'cadastro'),

     )
```

how can i managed that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `base.html` file you should make sure to use absolute paths instead of relative.

This is an example of an absolute path (note the leading forward-slash):

```
<a href="/cliente/cadastro/">A client</a>
    <!-- ^ leading slash -->
```

---

And this is what you should probably avoid:
This is an example of a relative path (no leading forward-slash):

```
<a href="cliente/cadastro/">ay, que barbaridad</a>
    <!-- ^ no leading slash -->
```